# Convert String containing Array of Integer to Integer Array IN Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a

```
let locationjson: String = "[\"43786\",\"55665\",\"62789\",\"90265\"]"
```

And I want to convert it to Arraylist / List in Swift... I have searched on StackOverflow but couldn't find an appropriate solution for Swift.

I want to output as `List<Integer>` containing the values `[43786,55665,62789,90265]`.

Comment: `locationjson` is _not_ of type `String`, but `[String]` (`Array<String>`).

Comment: No,  i am reading json from front end where from javascript i am using Json.Stringify  to Stringify the array of Integer... so array  gets converted to just String... now problem is i want to just extract the numbers form this stringifyied  String... but i don't know How to get this

Comment: `["43786","55665","62789","90265"]` is definitely an array of `String` (`[String]`) in Swift. If it's not supposed to be edit the question and provide the proper syntax.

Comment: My guess is that you have a *string* containing the JSON object `["43786","55665","62789","90265"]`. – Please lookup JSONSerialization, there are zillions of Q&A about it here on SO.

Comment: NO @vadian , it is NOT String Array of Integers but its just a String containing some special characters as " [ " and " ] " and numbers

Comment: Again: Look up (NS)JSONSerialization ...

Answer (score 4):

As Martin mentioned in the comments `JSONSerialization` is your friend:

```
let locationjson = "[\"43786\",\"55665\",\"62789\",\"90265\"]"
let data = locationjson.data(using: .utf8)!
if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String] {
    let intArray = array.flatMap { Int($0) }
    print(intArray)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using flatMap:

```
let locationjson  = ["43786", "55665", "62789", "90265"]
let result = locationjson.flatMap { Int($0) }
```

Comment: locationjson is not array ... its just character string  and i want to extract out the numbers out of it and add it into the list of integer

Comment: @VaibhavShimpi Do you mean the input is more like `"43786,55665,62789,90265"`?
i.e. It's a single string and the numbers are all separated by commas?

Comment: No @Jace , its "["43786,55665,62789,90265"]"  like this  which is just a string containing " [ "  , and  " ] "  as I have JSON.stringify(["43786,55665,62789,90265"]) , so entire Integer array getting converted to just a string...

Comment: @VaibhavShimpi Why would you put the numbers all in a single string, all in a single array? that's nonsense

Comment: bcoz i am storing it in DB as json directly

Comment: Why make this harder for yourself and store this array in a strange way? If you need to store these Integers as a String, just store it as "43786,55665,62789,90265"

Comment: it is easy to store direct JSON in DB and again read it after converting to required array by parsing Json

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like this?

```
var str:String = "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\"]"
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "")
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")

var arrStrNums = str.components(separatedBy: ",")

var nums:[Int] = []

for strNum in arrStrNums {
    if let num = Int(strNum) {
        nums.append(num)
    }
}

print("Number list: \(nums)")
```

Outputs:

```
Number list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Ah wait, I see your updated syntax, will update my answer.

Comment: it is String  "[ "1" , "2", "3"]"  containing  characters and special characters(square brackets)... and my question is just give me integers list i.e 1,2 ,3 out of this string

Comment: I've updated my answer to include handling the `\"` characters. The integers list is `nums` in my above answer.

Comment: This is a very fragile approach to deserialize a JSON object. It works in this particular case, but already fails if each comma is followed by a space (which is allowed with JSON). It also does not detect invalid input like `"[\"1,1\"]"`

Comment: Fair enough. I took his question exactly as is and answered exactly as is. I suppose it would be even better to try and understand the end goal of the question in context sometimes and offer a solution that handles more edge cases. I'll happily take that well deserved down vote.

Comment: hey, @Zhang,  thank you so much man , Its working.... really thanks... at least you understood the question.. thank once again

Comment: You are better off using vadian's answer, shorter to type and less fragile than mine.